# Root bone moving carry joint twice as far as it should

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, bone.constraints

I have everything parented to a root bone and my carry joint is constrained to the hand bone (this is so that I have the option to keyframe in influence and swap which hand the carry joint is in mid animation), however when I move the root bone the carry joint moves twice as far as it should instead of staying in the same position relative to the root bone.

Comment: While I don't understand any of the details of the question, it sounds like you're getting doubled deforms.  Two ways this can easily happen: object is both bone parented and has an armature modifier; or, object has two armature modifiers.